# find time nearest to the given array of times

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, time, logic

i'm facing a little complication in this logic please help me out....

so the thing is:

i have a list of times in a table like

9:00 am, 9:30 am, 10:00 am, 10:30 am, 11:00 am, 11:30 am, 12:00 pm, 12:30 pm, 1:00pm, 1:30 pm...........

so now if i have given a random time like **10:42 am** the logic should be in such a way that it should return **10:30 am**

please help me out with this logic........

it helps alot if it is sql-statement...

any help is very appreciated . . . . .

Thank you

Comment: Both javascript and sql in the tags? Err

Comment: @fge it helps me both ways i could use both javascript code and sql-statement....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get rid of your `am / pm` qualifiers - use the 24 hour clock.  Better yet, just use seconds or minutes since midnight.

If you've done that, you can then just use:

```
SELECT   time, ABS(time - usertime) AS diff
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY diff
LIMIT    1
```

That's actually MySQL syntax, but it should be easy to port to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is very probably preferred:

```
select max(datecol) from thetimetable where datecol <= thewantedtime
```

Comment: this will find the next time _on or before_ the requested time, not necessarily the nearest, which could be after.